# ggplot divergent lines with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to graph lines diverge from the reference point 'a' to other points such as 'b', 'c', 'd', etc.,

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(value = c(1.40438297796257, 1.44036790976986, 
1.37704383251482, 1.45355096018748, 1.40847559339844, 1.38860635968641, 
1.43714387291229), group = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"
), low = c(1.38956448514689, 1.40198829989962, 1.33523395978584, 
1.42008027933896, 1.37516232159193, 1.34823916425279, 1.397985577859
), up = c(1.41920147077825, 1.4787475196401, 1.4188537052438, 
1.487021641036, 1.44178886520494, 1.42897355512002, 1.47630216796558
), sem = c(0.00757411399256711, 0.0120426947992103, 0.0137959906464809, 
0.00953361452671253, 0.00945315870421568, 0.0130586010600045, 
0.0124407008862053)), .Names = c("value", "group", "low", "up", 
"sem"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot( df, aes( x = group, y = value, group = 1 ) ) +
  geom_line( size = 1 ) +
  geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, aes( ymin = low, ymax = up ), colour="black") +
  geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, 
                 aes( ymin = value - sem, ymax = value + sem ),
                 colour="red") +
  geom_point( shape = 21, size = 4, fill="white")
```

**Current Plot:**

[image]

**Expected Plot:**

[image]

Comment: I believe `ggplot` "connects the dots" between groups in this instance. That is why you need to repeat the reference values as in OganM's answer below. That is for it to draw a line between `a` and `b` you need an observation where `a = group1` and `b = group1`. Similarly for it to draw between `a` and `c` you need an observation where `a = group2` and `c = group2`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why you did `group = 1` but you need the `group` var to separate the lines. Here I created dummy data points that are identical to the first data point, to be at the same group as each of the data points. Note that if you are planning to use transparency this will cause problems and will need some further fiddling.

```
df = rbind(df[rep(1,5),],df)

df$lineGroup = c(1:6,1:6)

ggplot( df, aes( x = group, y = value, group = lineGroup ) ) +
    geom_line( size = 1 ) +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, aes( ymin = low, ymax = up ), colour="black") +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, 
                   aes( ymin = value - sem, ymax = value + sem ),
                   colour="red") +
    geom_point( shape = 21, size = 4, fill="white")
```

[image]

**Transparency issue**

If you do

```
ggplot( df, aes( x = group, y = value, group = lineGroup ) ) +
    geom_line( size = 1 ) +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, aes( ymin = low, ymax = up ), colour="black",alpha=.3) +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, 
                   aes( ymin = value - sem, ymax = value + sem ),
                   colour="red",alpha =.3) +
    geom_point( shape = 21, size = 4, fill="white")
```

You'll see the first point is darker due to presence of multiple data points there

[image]

To get rid of that you need to control transparency through `aes` as well by adding a column that controls visibility.

```
 df$alpha = c('visible', rep('hidden',5), rep('visible',6))

ggplot( df, aes( x = group, y = value, group = lineGroup ) ) +
    geom_line( size = 1 ) +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, aes( ymin = low, ymax = up,alpha= alpha ), colour="black") +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, 
                   aes( ymin = value - sem, ymax = value + sem,alpha=alpha),
                   colour="red") +
    scale_alpha_manual(name='',values  = c('visible' = 0.3,'hidden' = 0)) + 

    geom_point(aes(), shape = 21, size = 4, fill="white")
```

[image]

Comment: I used `group = 1` to avoid this error `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
adjust the group aesthetic?`

Comment: Edited in an explanation

Answer (score 2):

Using the same data and method as OganM's answer above, you can solve the transparency issue by using a de-duped dataset in the `geom_point`. This should work:

```
ggplot( df, aes( x = group, y = value, group = lineGroup ) ) +
    geom_line( size = 1 ) +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, aes( ymin = low, ymax = up ), colour="black") +
    geom_errorbar( width=.2, size = 1, 
                   aes( ymin = value - sem, ymax = value + sem ),
                   colour="red") +
    geom_point(data = df[!duplicated(subset(df,select=-lineGroup)),], 
               shape = 21, size = 4, fill="white")
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
df<-structure(list(value = c(1.40438297796257, 1.40438297796257, 
1.40438297796257, 1.40438297796257, 1.40438297796257, 1.40438297796257, 
1.44036790976986, 1.37704383251482, 1.45355096018748, 1.40847559339844, 
1.38860635968641, 1.43714387291229), group = c("a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), low = c(1.38956448514689, 
1.38956448514689, 1.38956448514689, 1.38956448514689, 1.38956448514689, 
1.38956448514689, 1.40198829989962, 1.33523395978584, 1.42008027933896, 
1.37516232159193, 1.34823916425279, 1.397985577859), up = c(1.41920147077825, 
1.41920147077825, 1.41920147077825, 1.41920147077825, 1.41920147077825, 
1.41920147077825, 1.4787475196401, 1.4188537052438, 1.487021641036, 
1.44178886520494, 1.42897355512002, 1.47630216796558), sem = c(0.00757411399256711, 
0.00757411399256711, 0.00757411399256711, 0.00757411399256711, 
0.00757411399256711, 0.00757411399256711, 0.0120426947992103, 
0.0137959906464809, 0.00953361452671253, 0.00945315870421568, 
0.0130586010600045, 0.0124407008862053), lineGroup = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("value", 
"group", "low", "up", "sem", "lineGroup"), row.names = c("1", 
"1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "11", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
), class = "data.frame")
```